# Anchor links that point to ID of a hidden element will cause browser to automatically show the element and scroll to it when clicked

Tags: html, css

Anchor links that point to ID of a hidden element will cause browser to automatically show the element and scroll to it when clicked. I've seen some girl post a demo of this, but I cannot find it anymore. No JavaScript please.

Comment: ok so you want us to search for something for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and tests I have concluded that Mozilla engine doesn't auto-show hidden divs when linked using anchors.

Answer (score 2):

Use an Octothorpe in the href attribute of the anchor element.

```
<a href="#SomewhereElse">Click here</a>
<div id="SomewhereElse">When you click the browser should scroll here</div>
```

Comment: Hidden, hidden div. After some research and tests I have concluded that Mozilla engine doesn't auto-show hidden divs when linked using anchors.